# css scrollbar for y-axis in fixed div panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My html content is like following and I want to a fixed sidebar that has 100% height. And scrollbar y should be appear when content added in **mainContent** or **Content**.

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              My Panel-1
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
              blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah
              blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah
              blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              My Panel-2
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
              blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah
              blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah
              blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my css is like this:

```
.mainContainer
{
    float:right;
    height: 100%;
    width:350px; 
    padding:3px; 
    background:#f00;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.Content
{ 
    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: remove overflow-y: hidden and modify overflow-y: auto to overflow-y:scroll and add position:fixed;

it seems like this
https://jsfiddle.net/467fz6rp/1/

Comment: do you mean position is important?

Comment: @Veeru - Add as an answer so bookmarker can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes to your styles:

remove

> overflow-y: hidden

and add

> overflow-y: scroll
>   position:fixed;

it will work for example check this jsfiddle.net/467fz6rp/1